# Is there a python equivalent to R's `with`?

Tags: python, r, scope

In R, the `with` function constructs an environment from some data - this allows you to refer to items in your data as if they are variables, so this:

```
with(list("a" = 12, "b" = 13), {
  print(a)
  print(b)
})
```

prints this:

```
[1] 12
[1] 13
```

Is there something similar in python? Perhaps that takes a dictionary where all the keys are strings and constructs an environment from it?

Comment: why would you want the `with` in python? what are you exactly looking for? seems like an xyproblem

Comment: no. there isn't. Just use a function if you need a new scope.

Comment: You can *kinda* do this with `exec`, but it is for most purposes a really bad idea. There's a reason Javascript deprecated its `with` statement.

Comment: I think I've learned the answer is "maybe but don't". I imagine I could achieve something similar with a function and kwargs in any case. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function which updates the locals of the function with the dictionary `dct` as variable assigned to values

```
import sys
def with_r(dct):

    sys._getframe(10).f_locals.update(dct)

    print(a, b, c) # <=== using the keys as variables

d = {'a':12, 'b':2, 'c':23}

with_r(d)

# 12 2 23
```

Comment: This isn't doing what you think it does, as you'll see from the [crash you get](https://ideone.com/J3SU5B) if you try to call `with_r` from another function.